# Calculate the length of lines traced over an image

Tags: c, formula, trigonometry, lines, trace

Ok, I've been struggling with this problem since a long time. I have some images I need to trace and extract some values from their pixels. The thing is I need the length of those lines over the image so I know when to stop trying to extract the values. These lines should be at all angles from the center of the image. Here is a description of how the traces happen on the image

http://s16.postimage.org/yzxwze6tf/Screenshot_at_2012_08_29_11_26_00.png

So p is the distance of the line from the center of the image (I have to calculate the lines at all distances), t are the values extracted from the image along the line and also the angle of the line since I need the whole 360 angles.

So When I programmed this I found these formulas to calculate the length of the lines.

```
t1y = -((Mhe - (p * cos(phi)))/sin(phi));
t1x = ((Nhe - (p * sin(phi)))/cos(phi));
t2y = ((Mhe + (p * cos(phi)))/sin(phi));
t2x = -((Nhe + (p * sin(phi)))/cos(phi));
```

On that code Mhe is half the width of the image and Nhe is half the height of the image. p is the distance of the line from the center of the image and phi is the angle. t1y t1x and t2y and t2x are the most extreme points where the line intersects the boundaries of the image so I choose one between t1x and t1y and another between t2x and t2y. If for example I choose t1x and t2y then I substract t2y from t1x (t2y-t1x) and so I get the length of the line. Here is another picture describing these values

http://s12.postimage.org/cw1rbdlqz/Screenshot_at_2012_08_29_11_47_06.png

Thing is when I apply these formulas to calculate the length of those lines I get crazy numbers like, for example,

Angle 153, length of the line 82 (this is fine since is within the image boundaries)

Angle 154, length of the line -2584

The second one is definitely not fine since it goes outside the image boundaries and it's even negative!

Will someone with trigonometry knowledge help me understand why I'm getting so different values from the formulas above? and if there's an easier way to calculate the length of those lines using the angle of the line, the dimensions of the image and the distance of the line from the center of the image.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you double-checked whether phi is in radians versus degrees?

Comment: I think they should be in degrees.